# Changing a negatively switch circuit to a positively switched circuit with a PNP transitor

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

I believe I am trying to do something relatively simple, but I am not versed in this sort of thing. Please forgive any error in terms or diagrams.

I have a turn signal circuit for a motorcycle. There is one positive and one ground. The positive is constantly hot. The ground is switched on and off to engage the turn signal. I want to convert this to a positively switched system.

I believe I can use a PNP transistor to do this.

If I connect the PNP base to ground and the PNP emitter to positive, the PNP collector would be a positively switched circuit?

I included the diagram below, but I may have used the wrong symbols.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqJp6o.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: `convert this to a positively switched system` ... why? ... what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: NPN transistor, or MOSFET, between lamp and ground ... positive signal will light the lamp .... look at microcontroller solenoid driver circuits

Comment: Do you want to change the motorcycle wiring itself or do you want to extract a positive turn signal from the existing motorcycle wiring for other processing?

Comment: I am trying to upgrade the turn signal on my motorcycle. I have an LED turn signal that has two different functions. The LED has two positives (one for each function – running light and turn signal) and a common ground. 

The wiring from the motorcycle can only offer functionality for the turn signal. One positive and only ground which is switched high or off for the turn signal operation. I can get a positive and ground source from a different place on the motorcycle to function for the running light. 

The problem is: I need a positive instead of a ground that controls the turn signal.

Comment: @Jens I want to extract a positive from the existing wiring.

Comment: Basically, I want a circuit that will allow the current to flow only if the ground is engaged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controlling some load using “Switched Gnd” can be done using circuit bellow.

When “Switched Gnd” is at Gnd the Led is glowing.

[image]

Edit: Switching with positive signal

[image]

Comment: that is the behavior now ... the OP want to change it

Comment: Why do you need a 22k resistor to the base of the transistor?

Comment: 22k is for limiting the base current. You cannot connect BE directly to voltage source because the base will burn.

Comment: This is probably a stupid question: Could you just connect the base to ground for it to switch allowing current through the transistor?

Comment: No way. Even 1.5V AA battery connected between BE is enough to destroy the base.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense! So then why is the 100K resistor there? I am unsure why that connection is there.

Comment: The base should not be floated. So when “switched ground” signal is not presented the 100k through 22k will pull the base to Vcc.